# SQL create new row with values unless row with 2 columns match

Tags: mysql, sql

I create my table by doing so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (uuid VARCHAR(128), item VARCHAR(48), value FLOAT(11))
```

When I insert values, I want UUID and ITEM together to unique. By that I mean, if there is an entry where uuid and item matches the new values, it will update that one. If not, it will create a new one. So I don't want UUID to have a unqiue key, nor ITEM. But I sorta want them to become unique together. So there can't be 2 entries where both UUID and ITEM match the other entry's UUID and ITEM.

If my explanation wasn't awful, does anyone know how that could be done?

Comment: why cant you create a new column that concats 'uuid' and 'item'  and make this new column unique??

Comment: Because that seems really unintuitive and hacky. I expect there to be a better way. I also want to be able to query the contents of each specific column and such, and that won't really work if I merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? First make uuid and item your primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (uuid VARCHAR(128), item VARCHAR(48), value FLOAT(11), PRIMARY KEY(uuid, item)) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

Then use, "ON DUPLICATE UPDATE"

```
INSERT INTO table_name(UUID, item, value)
VALUES ('315c383c-b977-11e4-a6d1-954287e1d27a',  'item1', 1.0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
[Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: Yes, that looks perfect! I will try at asap and mark this as answered if it works! Can you explain why you explicitly specify InnoDB, is that a requirement?

Comment: It's not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

To insert the rows only if it is a new combination

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT uuid,
       item,
       value
FROM   source_table S
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table_name T
                   WHERE  S.uuid = T.uuid
                          AND s.item = t.item)
```

To update the rows if the combination already exists

```
UPDATE table_name T
       JOIN source_table S
         ON S.uuid = T.uuid
            AND s.item = t.item
SET    T.value = S.value
```